# Linux default scheduler alternatives

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, scheduler

The Linux kernel implements the `Completely Fair Scheduling (SCHED_NORMAL)` algorithm as its default scheduling algorithm for scheduling real-time processes.

How to modify the linux kernel such that the default scheduling policy is set to `round-robin (SCHED_RR)` or any other scheduling policy ? Is there a generic way to do so ?  What files need to be exactly changed here ?

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Do you really want to change the scheduling for all processes or only enable real-time scheduling for a single process?

Comment: For a single process, I can easily use the `sched_setscheduler()` function to change its scheduling-policy, I want to change the scheduling of all processes. @koalo

Comment: maybe you'll get better answers at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Nope, didn't found anything. Also, the question is more code-specific rather than unix-specific, I need to know what code needs to be changed to achieve the above purpose. @torkleyy

Comment: I would rather look into some Linux kernel mailing list. Chances to meet a real subject matter expert are probably much better over there ...

Comment: I am not aware of a method to do that, but it is certainly possible (at least by recompiling the kernel). However, I do not think it is clever with a full fledged operating system such as Ubuntu, because there are so many processes running in parallel that can not really cope with the disadvantages of SCHED_RR. Maybe you can extend the question and describe what exactly you want to achieve and why it is not sufficient to enable SCHED_RR for single processes.

Comment: My current gut suggests that I only need to replace the macro SCHED_OTHER by SCHED_RR in the `core.c` code in the linux kernel's `sched` folder and then recompile it, but I don't know exactly what to do else, since there is a lot of code. Also, there is no specific need for SCHED_RR, all I want to learn is how to tweak linux kernel and customising it. @koalo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By all means, please tell me this is just an experiment :) I really can't see anything good coming out of trying such heresy.

That said, here's my try at it. First of all, we need to get a sandbox. I've used User Mode Linux (UML). For the kernel, I grabbed a random 4.10.0-rc1 repo, but any version would do. For the rootfs, the UML page provides a bunch of them [here](http://fs.devloop.org.uk/) (pitfall: not all of them work fine).

Steps to build the kernel are quite short:

```
export ARCH=um
make x86_64_defconfig
make
```

If you got the Slackware rootfs, you can now run as:

```
 ./vmlinux ubda=./Slamd64-12.1-root_fs
```

OK, cool. So we have a safe place to break some kernels. Let's get to it. As you probably know, the `init` (pid=1) is the first process and the parent of all the other processes. RT scheduling class is inherited (unless asked otherwise with a flag, see SCHED_RESET_ON_FORK in [man 7 sched](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html)). This means we might change the scheduling class for the `init` process and get its children to inherit the scheduling class by default.

This is easily doable with something like this:

```
diff --git a/init/main.c b/init/main.c
index b0c9d6facef9..015f72b318ef 100644
--- a/init/main.c
+++ b/init/main.c
@@ -951,8 +951,11 @@ static inline void mark_readonly(void)

 static int __ref kernel_init(void *unused)
 {
+       struct sched_param param = { .sched_priority = MAX_RT_PRIO - 1 };
        int ret;

+       /* Sit tight and fasten your seat belt! */
+       sched_setscheduler_nocheck(current, SCHED_FIFO, &param);
        kernel_init_freeable();
        /* need to finish all async __init code before freeing the memory */
        async_synchronize_full();
```

And it works!

```
root@darkstar:~# sleep 60 &
[1] 549
root@darkstar:~# ps -c
  PID CLS PRI TTY          TIME CMD
  536 FF  139 tty0     00:00:00 bash
  549 FF  139 tty0     00:00:00 sleep
  550 FF  139 tty0     00:00:00 ps
```

(By the way, SCHED_DEADLINE cannot be inherited, as noted in [man 7 sched](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the kernel code and `SCHED_NORMAL` is actually hard-coded in several places e.g. https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/sched/core.c#n2394

It might be possible to change it to `SCHED_RR` at all places, but as written in the comments it not recommended to do that. It will probably crash your system because, for example, long-running calculations will block the CPU.