# How to change the process scheduler in the Kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, scheduler, cfs

I'm working on my thesis for graduation. It's mainly about the performance of different schedulers in Linux benchmarks.

But I'm facing a difficulty. I can already compile the Kernel and use it, but I can't change the process scheduler, only the I/O Scheduler. I want to switch the default process scheduler, **CFS**, to another one like **BFS** or **O(1)**.

Does anyone know how to do that?

I tried searching for patches or directories to replace the CFS files, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Take a look at [sched_setscheduler (2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) syscall. Note that many schedulers are kind of experimental, and can be found in non-mainline kernels only. If you want to change the default one, that's a bit trickier, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957088/linux-default-scheduler-alternatives) looks like something that's worth a try.

Comment: Perhaps look at how CFS replaced the previous scheduler. The changes were merged in the 2.6.23 kernel which is recent enough to be in the mainline Linux kernel git repository.

Comment: It's not like you can simply "change" the scheduler of the kernel. There is no option to do that at build time, nor code in the kernel that implements a different scheduling algorithm than CFS. In order to change anything, you would have to take a deep dive into kernel code and change/restructure it to implement the algorithm you want. It is a very hard task. So the only real option you have is to look at repositories created by the authors of other schedulers like BFS (if they still exist) and try out their patches on old kernels. For the O(1) scheduler you can just go back to Linux 2.6.22.

Comment: (ok technically there is `SCHED_RR` and friends which do implement a different algorithm, of course, but still, I suppose that is not what you are talking about here)